# On entry save/update, centered text returns to left in rich text field

Tags: richtext, redactor

How am I to center text with in the rich text field type? It centers while I'm editing, then returns to left align on save (and on output). I feel like I'm missing something obvious here...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you create a Rich Text field, there is an option for `Clean up HTML` which is checked by default. The description underneath the setting reads:

> Removes spans, empty tags, and most style attributes on save.

When aligning text in Redactor, inline styling is added, which would be stripped away on save if the `Clean up HTML` option is checked.

You'll just need to uncheck this option in your field settings if you want inline styles to be saved.